# Waiting method in Bot Framework v4

Tags: c#, botframework

In version 3 of the Bot Framework, I could call a card and wait for the user's response:

```
context.Call(new MyHeroCardOptions(), MyResumeAfter);
```

- Where **MyHeroCardOptions** is a HeroCard type card and **MyResumeAfter** is the method that awaits the user's response.

Can someone guide me how to do that in the Bot Framework V4. Please do not include "ChoicePrompt", my goal is to do with a HeroCard since it is an Attachment.

I am using this form:

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TransportStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await OptionHeroCard.GetHeroCard(stepContext.Context);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions());
        }

public static class OptionHeroCard
    {
        public static async Task GetHeroCard(ITurnContext context)
        {
            var heroCard = new HeroCard
            {
                Title = "Documentation",
                Subtitle = "Microsoft Bot Framework Documentation",
                Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg") },
                Buttons = new List<CardAction> { 
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Opción 1", value: "Opción 1"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Opción 2", value: "Opción 2"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Ir a a web", value: "https://learn.microsoft.com/bot-framework"),
                },
            };
            var reply = context.Activity.CreateReply();
            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            reply.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
            await context.SendActivityAsync(reply);
        }
    }
```

I currently use a "TextPrompt" with a "Waterfall" to generate a wait, but I don't know if it's appropriate.

3. I didn't know that I can include HeroCard in a "choice prompts". An example would be great.

Comment: Are you saying you want to prompt the user by having them click a button on the hero card? Can you provide the actual hero card you're using? Did you know that choice prompts can use hero cards?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, 
1. That's right, that I click and that I can get the result of that click.
2. Code:

-
`private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TransportStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await OptionHeroCard.GetHeroCard(stepContext.Context);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions());
        }`

I currently use a "TextPrompt" with a "Waterfall", but I don't know if it's appropriate.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Always edit your question so you can provide *formatted* code. Also, you haven't answered the question about whether you knew that hero cards can be used in choice prompts. Why did you ask us not to include `ChoicePrompt`?

Comment: @KyleDelaney edited

Comment: When you name a function something like `GetHeroCard`, the expectation is that the function only returns a hero card and doesn't perform any actions with it. I think you should name that function something like `SendHeroCard` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want your choices to be turned into a hero card automatically, you can use [`ListStyle.HeroCard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.choices.liststyle#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Choices_ListStyle_HeroCard):

```
new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)) { Style = ListStyle.HeroCard }
```

If you want to use your own custom hero card, you can do something like this:

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TransportStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string[] options = new[] { "Opción 1", "Opción 2" };
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), new PromptOptions
    {
        Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(options),
        Prompt = CreateHeroCardActivity(options),
        Style = ListStyle.None, // We're displaying the choices ourselves so we don't want ChoicePrompt to do it for us
    });
}

private static Activity CreateHeroCardActivity(IEnumerable<string> options)
{
    var heroCard = new HeroCard
    {
        Title = "Documentation",
        Subtitle = "Microsoft Bot Framework Documentation",
        Images = new List<CardImage>
        {
            new CardImage("https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg"),
        },
        Buttons = options.Select(option => new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: option, value: option))
            .Append(new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Ir a a web", value: "https://learn.microsoft.com/bot-framework"))
            .ToList(),
    };

    return MessageFactory.Attachment(heroCard.ToAttachment()) as Activity;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For bot framework 4.7 preview, I've done it by calling 2 actions

```
 new SendActivity("@{YourHeroCardTemplate()}"),
 new TextInput()
        {
                Property = "dialog.heroCardResponse",
                Prompt = new ActivityTemplate("Please select an option"),
        },
```

Hope it can help you the idea for other version of bot framework