# Bot Framework V4 Choice Prompt with Hero Card c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service

We used to be able to use choice prompts with Hero Cards as the Prompt in a dialog like below, but for some reason this has stopped working. The card still displays correctly but when you select an option the prompt retries over and over.

```
var card = new HeroCard
{

    Text = "Please choose an option.",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
};

foreach (var cl in input.ComplexList)
{
    string objString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cl.complexObject);
    card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction(
        ActionTypes.PostBack,
        cl.Name,
        null,
        objString,
        objString,
        objString));
}

card.Buttons.Add(new CardAction(
        ActionTypes.PostBack,
        "Cancel",
        null,
        "Cancel",
        "Cancel",
        "Cancel"));

var promptOptions = new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment())                        
    };
            
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);
```

I see that we can now define the style of the prompt with             `AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)) { Style = ListStyle.HeroCard });`

Now my issue is that I was using the hero cards to hide some extra information in the button value to use in my next step in the waterfall dialog, is this just not an option anymore, or am I missing something?

If I set the choice prompt style to HeroCard and remove the hero card specified, then the choices only allow for text which is displayed to the user.

Comment: What version of core are you using?  Did it change?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1

Comment: .net Core 3.1, but botframework is not on the list of breaking changes.

Comment: It may not be obvious what change for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the style property in the PromptOptions

```
var promptOptions = new PromptOptions {
  Prompt = (Activity) MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment()),
  Style = ListStyle.HeroCard
};
```

in BotBuilderv4 the ChoicePrompt need a `IList<Choice>` in the PromptOptions

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices;

var choices = new List<Choice> () {
  new Choice() {
    Value = "Value1",
    // Synonyms
    Synonyms = new string[] {};
  },
  new Choice() {
    Value = "Value2",
    Synonyms = new string[] {};
  },
  new Choice() {
    Value = "Value3",
    Synonyms = new string[] {};
  },
};
var promptOptions = new PromptOptions() {
  Prompt = (Activity) reply,
  RetryPrompt = (Activity) retry,
  Choices = choices,
  /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
  Style = ListStyle.HeroCard,

};
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);
```

where the `Choice.Value`  is the value that you put in CardAction's `value` :

```
new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack,title : "Cancel", value : "Cancel");
```

in the next step you can get the user's choice with

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> NextStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

  var result = (FoundChoice) stepContext.Result;
  // you can parse it as an enum or use it as is
  string UserChoice = result.Value
  // your logic here

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution HiDDeN, but as mentioned this used to fine the way I used to do it until recently, and doing it the way you suggest doesn't allow for me to postback complex json objects as a reply from the card.

Comment: Yo Hidden, if you fix your question i will mark it as correct, have a look at this answer to fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434168/waiting-method-in-bot-framework-v4?rq=1